# Curl of a vector in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

Let there be a vector $u(z)$ in the complex plane. Are these two statements equivalent?

$$\nabla\times\overline u=\overline{\nabla\times u}$$

If not, why? I think they should be equal since $\nabla$ is only an operator.

Thank you for any replies in advance.

Comment: What is curl meant to be in this context?

Comment: The curl is a partial derivative in 3d space not a complex derivative